Error: Middle mouse button click is pasting only the first selection
I have this Ubuntu version installed:
>>lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble

When I open the default terminal - GNOME Terminal - Version 3.52.0 for GNOME 46 -  I can use mouse middle button to paste my last selection. But It only do once, if I select a new text it will keep pasting the first one I selected. I installed Alacrity and this issue is not present there.
Do you face same issue? Where can I check how to solve ? (without installing other terminal emulator)
Thank you.
